# Importing a PDF created in Numbers displaying incorrectly

Tags: graphics, floats, pdf

I created a LaTeX document using Overleaf and a diagram I made in Numbers and exported in PDF format. I included it into Latex like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=15cm, trim=1.8cm 11.9cm 2.5cm 1.7cm, clip]{Diagram.pdf}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And it is being displayed correctly by overleaf:
[image: Diagram on Overleaf]

However, when exporting it as a PDF on Overleaf and printing it, I get this:
[image: Diagram on Preview or Printed]

This is a link to the PDF used: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyku3gxe6b9utj8/Gegevens.pdf?dl=0

How do I get these lines to work?

Comment: This won't solve the problem, but you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/32374 Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @darthbith You think that is the issue?

Comment: No, I don't think that is the issue, but simply a piece of advice :-) It would be better if you could provide a link to the PDF of the figure (e.g. from Dropbox or something) so we can try it here

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Will do!

Comment: @darthbith Added a link to the PDF!

Comment: I can not reproduce this with `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder It only occurs for me when I change the width of the figure to something less than the original width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF produced by Numbers in combination with LaTeX generates a PDF that is rendered incorrectly by certain PDF-viewers like `Preview.app` and `Skim` (`Adobe Acrobat` seems to render it correctly).<sup>1</sup>

In order to fix this, you can use `ghostscript` to recode your PDF:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new-file.pdf original-file.pdf
```

[image]

---

1. Doing a quick preflight on the original PDF generated by Numbers reveals some syntax errors and compatibility with PDF version 1.4 although the file reports version 1.3

Comment: Why do you think the PDF is incompatible with pdfTeX?

Comment: You are right, it is not the PDF itself that is incompatible. It is the combination of the PDF generated by Numbers + LaTeX + certain PDF-viewers like Preview.app and Skim (but nor Adobe Acrobat). I will amend my answer accordingly.