# Lines in figure are not shown on pdf output

Tags: graphics, pdf, viewers, overleaf

I have prepared a graph in pdf format by using graph_tool, which is:

[image: Proper Image]

I have imported the figure as pdf into tex file. It looks properly on latex preview. However, if I take a pdf output of the tex file, then the lines disappears.

[image: How it looks on a Pdf file]

I am working on Overleaf site. They use Tex Live 2016. The tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{synthetic_out}\label{sfig:synth_out}
\caption{Capt}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve to see lines on pdf output, too ? Thanks.

EDIT: I have made the lines thicker. But it didn't help too. You can achieve the pdf file via [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Q1brbhqRQNQnB4SV80aUlWbUk).

Comment: Since LaTeX is not able to remove lines inside PDF files while including the PDF as image, the lines are likely present. But the lines are quite thin, thus they might vanish in the PDF viewer with the chosen zoom factor. Increase the zoom and review again.

Comment: It didn't affect. @HeikoOberdiek

Comment: Also the image seems to be much too large. When it is scaled down, the text becomes quite unreadable black noise. Try to regenerate the image with a smaller canvas size in the image program. When it is included in the PDF file, the font size of the text elements of the image should not be smaller than `\small` (or `\footnotesize`).

Comment: Can you put the image somewhere for downloading?

Comment: This is most likely a viewer issue: If you zoom in, do the lines appear?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is there really text in there?

Comment: @cfr Something like a uppercase letter with a digit (e.g. A1, C5). If the text has normal size, then the image dimensions must be huge. The image should be designed in the image program with a size that is close to the real size of its usage in the document. Then the text would be readable and the lines would be thicker and not vanish.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have thickened the lines. But it didn't help. I have also shared the file. You can find the link in the "EDIT" part  the question.

Comment: Exactly what is `\start{figure}` please update the MWE so something others can test without having to add/change anything

Comment: Making a naïve MWE with your data using the PDF you linked to, works fine using TeX Live 2016, previewers evince or Adobe Reader.

Comment: @daleif sorry for lack of info. I have added MWE on the question. It is tested on Overleaf site. They are using TeX Live 2016, too. When I take a pdf output, the lines does not show up.

Comment: Are they using tl16 yet? Have you downloaded the pdf and used a previewer from your computer, thus not relying on the browsers build in pdf viewer. This build in pdf viewers often have errors and thus some things are not shown correctly.

Comment: I think it is narrowing down the viewer issue, as @MartinSchröder mentioned. I am using Preview app on Mac, on which I can't see the lines. However, if I upload the same PDF file to Google Drive, it looks properly and as expected. Also, I think this post is relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227209/importing-a-pdf-created-in-numbers-displaying-incorrectly

Comment: The updated image from the "Edit" section of the question looks much better. The text can be read and the lines are visible. I do not have any problems with including the image in LaTeX.